# Writing a command to detect when in mdframed

Tags: conditionals, mdframed

I want to write a `marginnote` command that detects whether it is called within a [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) environment, in particular I want to be able to distinguish the following

1. normal text
2. normal math
3. text in `mdframed`
4. math in `mdframed`

I'm not a TeX expert and I've tried looking at `\ifinner`, `\ifhmode`, `\ifvmode`, `\ifmmode`, but I cannot distinguish the `mdframed` instances. See the code below to demonstrate my task. Is it possible to do what I want?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz, roundcorner=8pt, shadow,% 
shadowsize=8pt, innerbottommargin=10pt, splittopskip=20pt, splitbottomskip=20pt]{mdframed}

\newcommand{\nmarginnote}[1]{
\ifhmode
Detected hmode
\fi
\ifvmode
Detected vmode
\fi
\ifmmode
Detected mmode 
\fi
\ifinner
Detected inner
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Normal text}
Test \nmarginnote{Test}

\section*{Normal math}
\begin{align*}
A + B = C \nmarginnote{Test}
\end{align*}

\section*{Normal text in mdframed}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!10, nobreak=true, frametitle={Frame}]
this is an example \nmarginnote{Test}
\end{mdframed}

\section*{Math in mdframed}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!10, nobreak=true, frametitle={Frame}]
\begin{align*}
A + B = C \nmarginnote{Test}
\end{align*}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add to `mdframed` the setting of a conditional:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz,
  roundcorner=8pt,
  shadow, 
  shadowsize=8pt,
  innerbottommargin=10pt,
  splittopskip=20pt,
  splitbottomskip=20pt]{mdframed}

%%% Just for the test
\newcommand{\nmarginnote}[1]{%
  #1 (%
    \ifinmdframed MD-YES\else MD-NO\fi,
    \ifmmode MATH-YES\else MATH-NO\fi
  )%
}
%%% mdframed loads etoolbox so the commands are available
\newif\ifinmdframed
\AtBeginEnvironment{mdframed}{\inmdframedtrue}



\begin{document}

\section*{Normal text}
Test \nmarginnote{Test}

\section*{Normal math}
\begin{align*}
A + B = C \nmarginnote{Test}
\end{align*}

\section*{Normal text in mdframed}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!10, nobreak=true, frametitle={Frame}]
this is an example \nmarginnote{Test}
\end{mdframed}

\section*{Math in mdframed}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!10, nobreak=true, frametitle={Frame}]
\begin{align*}
A + B = C \nmarginnote{Test}
\end{align*}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Thus you can examine `\ifinmdframed` to see if you are in a `mdframed` environment.

Comment: Can you explain why you're setting the boolean globally?

Comment: @cgnieder Good question. :) Just laziness in looking at the documentation of `etoolbox`.

Comment: Ah, I see :) And I was sure there was some not so obvious but nonetheless profound reason...

Answer (score 9):

```
\def\md@envname{mdframed}
...
\ifx\@currenvir\md@envname in mdframed \fi
```

will detect if the current environment is `mdframed` (it is only true at the top level of the frame, it is false again inside the `align*` in the `mdframed` as there `\@currenvir` will be `align*`