# Automatically Detect When in an Mdframed frame title

Tags: conditionals, mdframed, frame-title

I would like to be able to detect when I am within a `frametitle={}` of an `mdframed` environment.  One way is to manually set a flag within the `\frametitle={}`, but wondering if there is some other way to detect that condition so that I don't have to adjust all uses of `frametitle={}`.

The MWE below yields the desired results:

[image]

as it sets a `toggle`

```
frametitle={\toggletrue{InMdframedFrameTitle}\Title}
```

but I want to achieve the same results without just

```
frametitle={\Title}
```

### Related Question:

- [Writing a command to detect when in mdframed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94058/writing-a-command-to-detect-when-in-mdframed)

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\mdfdefinestyle{MyStyle}{%
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=red!40,
    frametitlerule=true, 
}

\newtoggle{InMdframedFrameTitle}
\newcommand*{\TitleColor}{.}
\newcommand*{\Title}{%
    \iftoggle{InMdframedFrameTitle}{%
        \renewcommand{\TitleColor}{.}%
    }{%
        \renewcommand{\TitleColor}{red}%
    }%
    \textcolor{\TitleColor}{Newton's Laws}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[
    style=MyStyle, 
    frametitle={\toggletrue{InMdframedFrameTitle}\Title}% <--- Want to remove the \toggletrue
    %frametitle={\Title}%                                 <--- and use just this.
    ]
    One of the things that Newton is known for is \Title, which refer to \dots.
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patching `\mdfframedtitleenv` to set the toggle at the start seems to work:

```
\makeatletter
    \let\OLD@mdfframedtitleenv\mdfframedtitleenv
    \let\mdfframedtitleenv\relax
    \newrobustcmd*\mdfframedtitleenv[1]{%
        \global\toggletrue{InMdframedFrameTitle}%  <--- Set toggle
        \OLD@mdfframedtitleenv{#1}%                <--- Execute original definition
        \global\togglefalse{InMdframedFrameTitle}% <--- Clear toggle
    }
\makeatother
```

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
    \let\OLD@mdfframedtitleenv\mdfframedtitleenv
    \let\mdfframedtitleenv\relax
    \newrobustcmd*\mdfframedtitleenv[1]{%
        \global\toggletrue{InMdframedFrameTitle}%  <--- Set toggle
        \OLD@mdfframedtitleenv{#1}%                <--- Execute original definition
        \global\togglefalse{InMdframedFrameTitle}% <--- Clear toggle
    }
\makeatother

\mdfdefinestyle{MyStyle}{%
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=red!40,
    frametitlerule=true, 
}

\newtoggle{InMdframedFrameTitle}
\newcommand*{\TitleColor}{.}
\newcommand*{\Title}{%
    \iftoggle{InMdframedFrameTitle}{%
        \renewcommand{\TitleColor}{.}%
    }{%
        \renewcommand{\TitleColor}{red}%
    }%
    \textcolor{\TitleColor}{Newton's Laws}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[
    style=MyStyle, 
    %frametitle={\toggletrue{InMdframedFrameTitle}\Title}% <--- Want to remove the \toggletrue
    frametitle={\Title}%                                 <--- and use just this.
    ]
    One of the things that Newton is known for is \Title, which refer to \dots.
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```